# Windows two ethernet card settings

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have two ethernet cards and my route is like this:

```
IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.128.1   172.16.161.124     35
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         11.1.1.1                c    291

===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
           172.16.0.0    255.255.252.0     172.16.128.1     282
        192.168.123.0    255.255.255.0     172.16.128.1       1
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         11.1.1.1  Default
```

I want to connect to internet using 11.1.1.1 and if I connect to any server that ip adress 172.... or 192... I will use 172.16.128.1 gateway.

This works but when I restart the computer, the metric of 172.16.161.124 is setted smaller than 11.1.1.1, so my internet connects from 172.16.161.124.

Comment: Set metrics to 10 for your internet coonection and 12 for the secondary connection.